# Thread safety concerns with PUMA (using multiple threads) and MRI/jruby

Tags: ruby, concurrency, jruby, puma

I understand the basics concerns of shared state in a multi-threaded environment - even when using MRI with the GIL/GVL.  But I'm curious if there are different concerns when considering MRI + Puma vs jruby + Puma (assuming Puma is configured to use multiple threads in both cases).

Also, what are the critical sections involving shared state in the aforementioned cases and how would this differ in programs that aren't fundamentally request-driven (like ones that would leverage a web server like Puma)?

Thanks for your time and consideration; any recommendations regarding good resources on these topics would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you fully read https://github.com/puma/puma?

Comment: Could you define your question a little better? Are you asking how the threading models differ in MRI to JRuby or is your question more around how a server like puma uses threads to handle concurrency?

Comment: There are not really any differences in how thread-safety is approached under MRI and Jruby. In some cases you can 'get away with' bad code under MRI, that is technically unsafe but you may never see the race condition, that in JRuby you'd see the race condition more frequently. But thread-safe code and techniques are really the same in both. I'm not sure what you mean by "programs that aren't fundamentally request-driven (like ones that would leverage a web server like Puma)" -- most web apps are fundamentally request driven, and Puma is for web apps. Do you mean websockets or something?